# Simulate view unloaded because of low memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was following a sample code from Apple here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Listings/AppDelegate_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848-AppDelegate_m-DontLinkElementID_4

It is an example showing how to use SearchDisplayController to do search on a table.

The codes related to my question are:

1. in viewDidLoad -

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        self.title = @"Products";

        // create a filtered list that will contain products for the search results table.
        self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.listContent count]];

        // restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning.
        if (self.savedSearchTerm)
        {
            [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchWasActive];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
            [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];

            self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
        self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

1. in viewDidDisappear -

```
    -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        // save the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is re-created
        self.searchWasActive = [self.searchDisplayController isActive];
        self.savedSearchTerm = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text];
        self.savedScopeButtonIndex = [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex];
    }
```

So, it says that it is saving the state of the search UI so that it can be restored if the view is recreated.

It also says that "it restore search settings if they were saved in didReceiveMemoryWarning."

So my understanding is, when memory is low, this view might be unloaded. It might be recreated again when user click on that tab to view that view.

So I want to simulate the low memory situation where my view gets unloaded, so that I can confirm that the logic where search terms get restored is working. But I failed.

1. I put a trace in viewDidLoad; it never fires more than one time, i.e., the view was never unloaded
2. I used the iPhone Simulator - simulate memory warning - the view never gets unloaded also.

To summary my question:

1. Will a loaded view in a tab bar contoller gets unloaded by iOS because it faces low memory?
2. If the answer to the above question is Yes, then does the iOS Simulator able to reproduce that?

Comment: What do you mean by "witness"? Seeing how the view will disappear in front of your eyes? That will not happen, cause de default implementation is checking if the view can be released.

Comment: hi yan.kun, I mean I would like to see how my view gets unloaded and recreated because of low memory warning. Do you mean a view in a tab bar controller will never gets unloaded due to low memory? (sorry i really have no idea)

Comment: I think he just meant that you can't "witness" the unloading of a view that is being displayed. If you want to see the behaviour of the didReceiveMemoryWarning on your view, you will have to call the method while it's not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm can't be positive about this answer but in my experience, it works this way.

If your UIViewController is registered as one of your UITabBarController's viewControllers and if the UITabBarController is the rootViewController of your UIWindow, the memory warning should be relayed to your UIViewController. If not I believe there a missing transition. To find out where, you could NSLog every UIViewController from the rootViewController to the UIViewController you want, and see where it stops.

Now, if you want to test the didReceiveMemoryWarning of your UIViewController, you can just call the method yourself, when another View is loaded or by using a timer.